# what's the different between the hotspot jvm interpreter and jit

Tags: jvm-hotspot

what's the different between the hotspot jvm interpreter and jit?I had got confused from the opinion from the book i had read, the interpreter execute the code line by line, does it mean that the interpreter will translate the bytecode to the machine code and then execute them?

Comment: There are no lines in the bytecode, hence there is no such thing as “line by line” execution. Besides that, the difference between interpreter and compiler is well defined for decades, quiet independently from bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler and Interpreter do the same job of converting High lavel code to machine understandable code

interpreter takes the single instruction of the code, translates it into an intermediate code and then into a machine code, executes it and takes another instruction and continue for all the instructions

JIT compiler does optimization on high lavel code and converts entire code into machine understandable code through scanning all the code.

You can find the more details here - http://www.whizlabs.com/blog/what-is-just-in-time-compiler-difference-between-compiler-and-interpreter/